# ScrollView not scrolling when label text is big string

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a scroll view programatically, but it is not working as expected. Here is my code.

```swift
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.leadingAnchor(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
        scrollView.trailingAnchor(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        scrollView.topAnchor(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
        scrollView.bottomAnchor(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)

        let imageview = UIImageView()
        scrollView.addSubview(imageview)

        let contentLabel = UILabel()
        scrollView.addSubview(contentLabel)

        imageview.leadingAnchor(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
        imageview.trailingAnchor(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        imageview.topAnchor(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
        imageview.heightAnchor(equalTo: 300)
        imageview.backgroundColor = .cyan

        contentLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        contentLabel.leadingAnchor(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
        contentLabel.trailingAnchor(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        contentLabel.topAnchor(equalTo: imageview.bottomAnchor, constant: 16)
        contentLabel.bottomAnchor(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16)
        contentLabel.text = BIG_TEXT
```

I'm trying to add an image view and text below that. When the text content is more I should make it scrollable. Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: Why are constraining ImageView and Label to parent view and to ScrollView?

Comment: yeah, got the mistake... thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a `UIStackView` as the first child of your `UIScrollView` and add your subviews to it with the `addArrangedSubview` method:

```
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.leadingAnchor(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
        scrollView.trailingAnchor(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        scrollView.topAnchor(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
        scrollView.bottomAnchor(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)

        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.leadingAnchor(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor)
        stackView.trailingAnchor(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor)
        stackView.topAnchor(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor)
        stackView.bottomAnchor(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor)
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor)

        let imageview = UIImageView()
        imageview.heightAnchor(equalTo: 300)
        imageview.backgroundColor = .cyan
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageview)

        let contentLabel = UILabel()
        contentLabel.text = BIG_TEXT
        contentLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(contentLabel)

        stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
```